# cell.selected doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When I selected a row, text color turns white. however, when I scroll to refresh the row, the text color turns back to black. so I have added a logic if(cell.selected). However it didn't work. when I scroll. the code can't get into if case.Here is the code :-

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let selectedCell:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
    for subview in selectedCell.subviews {
        if let view = subview as? UILabel {
            view.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        }
    }
 }

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var renderWidth:CGFloat = 8
    var renderYPosition:CGFloat = 15
    let cell:UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "idcell")
    let date = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(renderWidth, renderYPosition, 110, 20))
    let dateText = "asdasdsad"
    date.text = dateText
    if (cell.selected) {
        date.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }
    cell.addSubview(date)
 }
```

Comment: what do you mean by "scroll to refresh the row"? Did you call any functions like `reloadData`?

Comment: no. i mean cellforrowatindexpath

Comment: why don't you reuse your cell?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new `UITableViewCell` everytime. It is recommended to reuse it.

Instead of creating a new cell with this:

```
let cell:UITableViewCell=UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "idcell")
```

Use this to reuse the cell:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellIdInStoryboard", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
```

The identifier should be the same as the one you set in storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your if clause in cellForRowAtIndexPath function and also you create cell instance everytime you load the tableview.You need to reuse tableview cells.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   var renderWidth:CGFloat = 8
   var renderYPosition:CGFloat = 15
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("idcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! YourTableViewCell
   let date = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(renderWidth, renderYPosition, 110, 20))
   let dateText = "asdasdsad"
   date.text = dateText
   if (cell.selected) {
       date.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
   } else {
       date.textColor = UIColor.blackColor() // You didn't add else
   }
   cell.addSubview(date)
}
```